# Ansible multiple hosts with port forwarding

Tags: python, networking, portforwarding, ansible

I have hosts inventory with multiple hosts each with port forwarding, Hosts file is :

```
[all]

10.80.238.11:20003

10.80.238.11:20001

10.80.238.11:20007

10.80.238.11:20009
```

I am trying to ping them with a playbook, but always get response from first entry in this case `10.80.238.11:20003` not from others. Authentication is on place, whatever host I move to first place I get response from it but not others, my playbook is:

```
---
- hosts: all

  remote_user: root

  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: test connection

    ping:
```

Any idea how to fix this???

Comment: So these are VM's running on the same host? The VM's don't have their own IP addresses? - you're just forwarding a port on the host to some port on the guest, right?

Comment: Not VMs, each port is a specific hardware blade (server) in lab and have IP which is accessible only from this 10.80.238.11 server, That is why I am using port forwarding from my machine to bypass this middle machine (10.80.238.11)

Comment: Hey @sohailsahi. Could you show the inventory file of how you have specified the solution suggested by @leucos?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I suppose that the port forwarding you're doing is for SSH.

So you have to tell ansible which ssh port to connect to. The problem is that all your hosts have the same IP. So you have to use hostnames, so Ansible can distinguish them.

Let's assume that you refer to host with SSH port forwarded to `2000X` as `hostX`, then the right syntax to specify ssh port along with the host IP is :

```
host3 ansible_ssh_port=20003 ansible_ssh_host=10.80.238.11
host1 ansible_ssh_port=20001 ansible_ssh_host=10.80.238.11
host7 ansible_ssh_port=20007 ansible_ssh_host=10.80.238.11
host9 ansible_ssh_port=20009 ansible_ssh_host=10.80.238.11
```

You can then issue :

```
ansible host3 -m ping
```

or even :

```
ansible all -m ping
```

Note that you should not create an `all` group since Ansible creates it automagically.